# Proof: Show that if A is similar to $B$ and $A$ is nonsingular, then $B$ must also be nonsingular and $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are similar

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that if A is similar to $B$ and $A$ is nonsingular, then $B$ must
>   also be nonsingular and $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are similar:

I can prove that $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are similar, but **I am unsure of how to show $B$ that is nonsingular.**

Work:

$A=S^{-1}BS$

$A^{-1}=(S^{-1}BS)^{-1}$

$A^{-1}=S^{-1}B^{-1}(S^{-1})^{-1}$

$A^{-1}=S^{-1}B^{-1}S$

Also, my testbook says that if $B$ is similar to $A$ then exists a $S$ such that $B=S^{-1}AS$. The "placement" of $B$ and $A$ cannot be swapped right? For example if $B$ is similar to $A$, I can't say that $A=S^{-1}BS$?

Comment: Being similar is an equivalence relation. In particular it is symmetric. Assume $A=S^{-1}BS$ then $B=T^{-1}AT$ with $T=S^{-1}$

Comment: Your work is good, what do you want additionally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove $B$ Nonsingular

A matrix $B$ is nonsingular/invertible if exists a matrix $A$ such that $AB=BA=I$

$$A=S^{-1}BS\iff SAS^{-1}=B$$

- $$SAS^{-1}=B$$

  $$SAS^{-1}S=BS$$

  $$SAA^{-1}=BSA^{-1}$$
  $$SS^{-1}=BSA^{-1}S^{-1}$$
  $$I =B(SA^{-1}S^{-1})$$
- $$SAS^{-1}=B$$
  $$S^{-1}SAS^{-1}=S^{-1}B$$

$$A^{-1}AS^{-1}=A^{-1}S^{-1}B$$
$$SS^{-1}=SA^{-1}S^{-1}B$$
$$I = (SA^{-1}S^{-1})B$$

Answer (score 0):

A is similar to B if and only if A=R^-1BR for a regular matrix R. From there RAR^-1=B. The product of multiplication of regular matrices is also a regular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $ B $ has an inverse, you need to find a matrix, call it $ X $, such that $ B X = I $, the identity.

Now, *if* $ B $ has an inverse, then $ B^{-1} = ( S A S^{-1} )^{-1} = S A^{-1} S^{-1} $.

Why?  If $ A = S B S^{-1} $ then you can multiply both sides from the left by $ S^{-1} $ and both sides on the right by ....  and get that $ B

So you take $ X = S A^{-1} S^{-1} $ and you check that $ B X = I $.